# send URL request, without leaving page

Tags: javascript, url, streaming, redirect

I have a web-page, with a streaming web-camera. The camera pans and tilts, using a script on the camera's internal web-server. I cannot modify the  script, its output, is a web-page that says "OK".

When a user comes to  my page, I want them to be able to use arrow keys to pan the camera, but not have the script that sends out the request, leave the page with the camera stream. This source, will pan the camera, but you have to click back, to get to the stream. here  is my source:

```
<head>
    <?php
    $url = "http://Camera-server-IP/decoder_control.cgi?user=admin&pwd=password&command=2";
    ?>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).keypress(function (e){ 
    if(e.keyCode == 37) // left arrow
    {
    window.location.href = <?php echo "\"" . $url . "\""; ?>; 
    }

    else if(e.keyCode == 38)    // up arrow
    { 
$(window.location.href = "http://Camera-server-IP/decoder_control.cgi?user=admin&pwd=password&command=6"); 
    }

    else if(e.keyCode == 39)    // right arrow
    { 
    window.location.href = "http://Camera-server-IP/decoder_control.cgi?user=admin&pwd=password&command=4";  

    }

    else if(e.keyCode == 40)    // Down arrow
    { 
    window.location.href = "http://Camera-server-IP/decoder_control.cgi?user=admin&pwd=password&command=0";      
    }
});
</script>
<title>Navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
<br><h2>use arrows to navigate.</h2> 
<iframe src="http://Camera-server-IP/videostream.cgi?user=user&pwd=Password" width="330" height="260"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Camera-server-IP is the actual Camera Webserver address.
Why is every navigation arrow done differently? because I’m trying to figure this out.

what can I do to use the arrow keys to send the url requests to the camera, but simultaneously stay on the page where the camera is streaming?

Comment: Have you considered sending the pan requests via AJAX?

Comment: As an aside, you don't want to embed you camera username and password in the html/javascript. Users can see it.

Comment: I haven’t used ajax ever. yeas right about the use of javascript, but i'm trying to break my problems down into manageable parts.  I haven’t got a single php script / form to even move the camera, so Im trying JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is moving forward because you are setting the window location to the new link. What you want to do is use AJAX to make the call which should leave you on your current page afterwards. JQuery is not required for this, but would make things much easier for you.

Example using Jquery:

```
if(e.keyCode == 38)    // up arrow
{ 
    $.get("http://Camera-server-IP/decoder_control.cgi?user=admin&pwd=password&command=6", function() {
        //on successful call
    });
}
```

You can see more info on requests using jquery at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I've updated my post with an example of making the request using JQuery

Comment: He's already using jquery. See the first script tag in his post.

Comment: Ah, so he is! Should have read closer - I've taken away the part of my answer that says to add it in

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I've got something to go on, and Ill look into more ajax